# Using Langchain with custom retrievers

Tags: vector, vectorization, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I have this requirement, where i want to create a knowledge retriver which will call the API to get the closest matching information, I know that we have these integrations in langchain with multiple vector stores, but we have requirement were we have to call the API to find the closest matching document how can we create our custom retriver in langchain which will call this API to get the nearest matching informtaion

I'm trying to build the custom retriver in langchain but still not able figure it out

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Normally you would create a CustomRetriever class extending the BaseRetriever and BaseModel, implementing the functions get_relevant_documents and aget_relevant_documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom Retriever:

```
class URRetrival(BaseRetriever):

def __int__(self):
    pass

def _get_relevant_documents(
        self, query: str, *, run_manager: CallbackManagerForRetrieverRun
) -> List[Document]:
    # response = URAPI(request)
    # convert response (json or xml) in to langchain Document like  doc = Document(page_content="response docs")
    # dump all those result in array of docs and return below
    return result_docs

async def _aget_relevant_documents(
        self,
        query: str,
        *,
        run_manager: AsyncCallbackManagerForRetrieverRun,
        **kwargs: Any,
) -> List[Document]:
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

URRetrival : will be your Retrival name
_get_relevant_documents : will call when your chain run and its looking for relevant docs

now you can add any kind of implementation inside _get_relevant_documents method and return whatever relevant for you

Answer (score 1):

You can call any api using the following implementation and use the api as the retriever. As in my case I didn't have access to the redis vector store. But one api was open to me using which I could get the n records (text chunks) based on threshold.

Implementation in python:

```
from langchain.schema.retriever import BaseRetriever, Document
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any, Dict, List, Optional 
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManagerForRetrieverRun

class CustomRetriever(BaseRetriever):
    api_token_key:str
    api_end_point:str
    api_redis_index_name:str
    threshold_for_search_api:str
    
    def _get_relevant_documents(self, query: str, *, run_manager: CallbackManagerForRetrieverRun) -> List[Document]:
        """
        _get_relevant_documents is function of BaseRetriever implemented here

        :param query: String value of the query

        """
        result_docs = list()
        headers = {
            'apiToken': f'{self.api_token_key}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        data = '{"output":"*","query": "@similarity:' + query + '","index":"' + self.api_redis_index_name + '"}'

        response = requests.post(f'{self.api_end_point}',
                                 headers=headers,
                                 data=data)
        list_of_val = response.json()
        least_score = 1
        least_score_index = 0
        threshold_val = float(self.threshold_for_search_api)
        for c, i in enumerate(list_of_val):
            fetched_score = i["score"]
            if least_score < fetched_score:
                least_score = fetched_score
                least_score_index = c
            if fetched_score <= threshold_val:
                doc = Document(page_content=i["content"])
                result_docs.append(doc)

        if len(result_docs) == 0:
            i = list_of_val[least_score_index]
            doc = Document(page_content=i["content"])
            result_docs.append(doc)
        return result_docs
```

Then initialize the retriever as:

```
retriever_r = CustomRetriever(api_token_key=<your key>,
                              api_end_point=<your api endpoint>,
                             api_redis_index_name = <your redis index name>,
                             threshold_for_search_api= "0.5")
```

Then use the retriever in qa chain:

```
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm, 
    chain_type='map_reduce', 
    retriever=retriever_r, 
    chain_type_kwargs={"question_prompt": question_prompt_template, "combine_prompt": combine_prompt_template},
    verbose = True
)
```

Now you have a custom retriever that you can use for your custom QA chain

Answer (score 0):

On your API search results you can use tool to self ask with search that may help you finding the exactly match. Best option is vector similarity search where you have lots of capabilities to control your results.

```
        from langchain import OpenAI, SerpAPIWrapper
        from langchain.agents import initialize_agent, Tool
        from langchain.agents import AgentType

        # you can define a different llm
        llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
        search = SerpAPIWrapper()
        tools = [
            Tool(
                name="Intermediate Answer",
                func=search.run,
                description="useful for when you need to ask with search",
            )
        ]

        self_ask_with_search = initialize_agent(
            tools, llm, agent=AgentType.SELF_ASK_WITH_SEARCH, verbose=True
        )
        self_ask_with_search.run(
            "You can apply more filters with this query here ?"
        )
```